# Image resizing - recommended sizes for different screen resolutions

Tags: android, ios, image, bitmap, jpeg

Eg, I have an Image display on ios/android 200pixels wide and 150 height (4:3 format).

Usually the user will upload a photo from Gallery (about 1-4MB large).

To cater for different screen 'resolutions' of various low-end and high-end devices,

1. what should be a good Width/Height I should resize the original photo to?
   I'm currently using 200w x 150h, but I think this will look bad on retina displays or higher
2. let's say using JPG, should I scale down to
   a) lower resolution photo (eg. 200w x 150h) but use higher JPG quality
   vs b) higher resolution photo (eg 300w x 225h) but use lower JPG quality

appreciate if anyone has a good article link to share regarding photo trade-off and how to handle it for different phone resolutions/quality.

Comment: Why do you have to resize the original photo?

Comment: You can use constantlayout. And set the imageview ratio ‘ app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:3"’ and you can add constraints to the parent so it will cover the same amount of area on all phones.  Also here is the guide to load images efficiently on android. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.   You should not load full images as it can lead to OOM crashes

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk The original photo is 1-4MB which is way too big to use in a web server and android/ios app. the server needs to re-size it to maybe 10KB or so.

Comment: @Abhi I need this in a server - ios/android client over internet. hence picture needs to size down.  what I'm asking is actually what are good sizes to re-size it to.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. I’d suggest adding argument to url “ &size=small “ and keep the original image as it is. So server can have multiple size images. Then on client side you can check the device’s screen size or pixels and load the correct size images based on that